# Search words by delimiter in PHP and put them into array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string in PHP that contains this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <p>Hi! $username$, your email is $email$</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

This is stored in a database and I have a lot of them. The variables between $ can be different in each record. I want to get the name of the variables and store them into an array, for example:

```
array('username', 'email');
```

Thanks

EDIT: The document HTML is dynamic and stored in database, for example I can also have something like this:

```
<span>Test of $user$ with the $test$ and $foo$ and also a $foo2$ var</span>
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('/\$([^\$]*)\$/', $template, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);`

Comment: Thats it Mark Baker, it worked. Please write it as a Reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` function.

try below code:

```
$html = '<html>
<head>
<body>
  <p>Hi! $username$, your email is $email$</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>';

preg_match_all("/\\$(.*?)\\$/", $html, $matches1);

$required_array = $matches1[1];

print_r($required_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => username
    [1] => email
)
```

Comment: Ah shoot, I was 33 seconds too slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content  = "<html>
<head>
<body>
  <p>Hi! $username$, your email is $email$</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>";
$p = explode("$", $content  );

echo $p[2]; // username
echo $p[4]; // email
```

Comment: Hi, i can have this (is stored in mysql with records): Test of $user$ with the $test$ and $foo$ and also a $foo2$ var

Comment: @Sergio, if you have more than two 'variables' between $$ you can use again proposed solution with `explode()` but to take every `even` element from the array, i.e. 2, 4, 6, 8.

Comment: yep, exactly - all even elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/(?:Hi! )(.*)(?:, your email is )(.*)(?:<\/p>)/", $input_line, $output);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ffb

Comment: You may need to use preg_match_all since it's a multiline string?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to extract the variables

```
$string = '<html>
<head>
<body>
<p>Hi! $username$, your email is $email$</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>';
    $pat= '/\$(\w*)\$/';
    preg_match_all($pat, $string, $pat_array);

   $first  =  $pat_array[1][0];
   $second =  $pat_array[1][1];
   $final_array =array($first,$second);

   ?>
```